# Open page on double clicking a list item

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple select menu with some list items which are dynamically inserted when the page is loaded.

```
<select id="viewTasks" name="viewTasks" size=10 style="width: 100%;">
    <option>Task 1</option>
    <option>Task 2</option>
    <option>Task 3</option>
    <option>Task 4</option>
</select>
```

I would like to show the user a specific page whenever he/she **double-clicks** on any single list item. The page I want to show will be displayed according to the data in the list item string.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: @Soundz I'd like to avoid it since I'm not fully familiar with it yet. However, I'd like to see your solution anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fiddle that does what you want (pure javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/S3KN4/3/

```
var initializeListeners = function() {

    console.log('initializeListeners');

    var viewTasksElement = document.getElementById('viewTasks');

    viewTasksElement.addEventListener('dblclick', showPage, false);

}

var showPage = function() {

    console.log('showPage');

    var viewTasksElement = document.getElementById('viewTasks');

    var taskText = getSelectedTaskText(viewTasksElement);

    if (taskText) {

        // do something
        console.log('selected task: ' + taskText);

    }

};

var getSelectedTaskText = function (selectElement) {

    console.log('getSelectedTaskText');

    if (selectElement.selectedIndex == -1) {

        return null;

    } else {

        return selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;

    }

}

initializeListeners();
```

Comment: This worked perfect and did everything I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#viewTasks").dblclick(function()
    {
        var index = $(this).find(":selected").index();

        if(index == 0)
        {
            //do task 1
        }
        else if(index == 1)
        {
            // do task 2
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#viewTasks option').dblclick(function() {
 //do something
});
```

or raw:

```
<select id="viewTasks" name="viewTasks" size=10 style="width: 100%;">
    <option ondblclick="someFunction(1);">Task 1</option>
    <option ondblclick="someFunction(2);">Task 2</option>
    <option ondblclick="someFunction(3);">Task 3</option>
    <option ondblclick="someFunction(4);">Task 4</option>
</select>
<script>
  function someFunction(item) {

     switch(item) {
       case 1: ...
     }
  }
</scritp>
```

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd solution is just what I needed. Silly question, but how do I access the string "Task 1" from within the "someFunction"?

Comment: i have added an answer that does not require jquery and gives you the option text ...

Comment: by passing the item argument to `someFunction()` inside the switch statement you can define where to go, or to make it simpler just pass the url you want to link, then you just have to do: `<option ondblclick="document.location.href='http://your.link'">`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event:

```
$('#viewTasks').dblclick(function() {
  alert('The item was double-clicked!');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cDv7/

Answer (score 0):

As your options are dynamically inserted you need to use jQuery's `.on` method.

```
  $(function() {
    $(document).on("dblclick", "#viewTasks", function(){
       // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    });  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the MDN definition of the DOM event `ondblclick` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.ondblclick)

[Here is a working example jsFiddle from referencing that definition.](http://jsfiddle.net/R2Nrf/)

jQuery was only used in this example to run the initialization event in jsFiddle, you could put it in the body `onLoad` handler like they show on the MDN reference page.

Basically, you get the element that you want to handle the double click event for, and assign either a user-defined function, or an anonymous function to run when that event occurs. You do not absolutely need jQuery for this, but it is a perfect example of how jQuery can make things easier for you when it comes to handling events from DOM objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function(){
    initElement();
});

function initElement()
 {
 var p = document.getElementById("foo");
 // NOTE: showAlert(); or showAlert(param); will NOT work here.
 // Must be a reference to a function name, not a function call.
 p.ondblclick = showAlert;
 };

function showAlert()
 {
 alert("ondblclick Event detected!")
 }
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <span id="foo">My Event Element</span>
<p>double-click on the above element.</p>

</body>


</html>
```